# How can we help my 7-year-old brother stop wetting the bed?

Tags: primary-schooler, siblings, bed-wetting, enuresis

I have a 7-year-old, younger brother. Sometimes, he wets the bed. He wants to stop doing this, but he says he can't control it. He doesn't even know when he does it. Does anyone have any advice on how we can stop his bed-wetting problem?

Comment: Take a look at some of the other questions tagged [tag:bed-wetting] on the site. In particular, [this answer](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/3617/4054) has some excellent advice, and [this one](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/16682/4054) is also quite comprehensive.

Comment: Has your brother always done this?  Or did he go years without wetting the bed, and then start wetting the bed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good you are looking out for your brother!  Hey, tell him *don't worry about it*... he'll grow out of it someday. Lots of kids do that, and boys are notorious.

So, don't worry about, just put some things in place to protect him and the bed, like a protective cover, and some towels, etc.  Then, make sure no more fluids after a certain time (depending on when he goes to bed) and make him go pee just before bed.  Finally, get him up in the middle of the night to go pee, so his brain can get used to it.

Comment: He still does it, I mean that he's 9yrs old now.

Comment: There are nose drops that help many kids by simulating a natural hormone that allows the child to wake when they feel the need.

Comment: Buy bed-side bedwetting alarm or try Dr. Sagie's Bedwetting therapy.

Answer (score 0):

Something your parents might want to look into is his frequency of bowel movements. Constipation can cause the intestines to push against the bladder at night and cause leakage. There are many powders with insoluble fiber in them that you add to drinks that can help relieve that source of pressure on the bladder.